# Delete posts with custom field date older than current date via cronjob

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, cron-task

I want to make a cron job witch deletes all posts older than the date in a custom field of the post. I got following function within my functions.php My custom field name is `bewerbungs_frist`.

```
    function foobar_truncate_posts(){
    global $wpdb;

    $currenttime = new DateTime();
    $currenttime_string = $currenttime->format('Ymd');

    # Set your threshold of max posts and post_type name
    $post_type = 'job';

    # Query post type
    $query = "
        SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts
        WHERE post_type = '$post_type'
        AND post_status = 'publish'
        ORDER BY post_modified DESC
    ";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($query);

    # Check if there are any results
     if(count($results)){
            foreach($results as $post){

                $customfield = get_field('bewerbungs_frist', $post->ID);
                $customfield_object = new DateTime($customfield);
                $customfield_string = $customfield_object->format('Ymd');


                if ( $customfield_string < $currenttime_string ) {

                    echo "The value of the custom date field is in the past";
                    echo $customfield_string;


                    $purge = wp_delete_post($post->ID);
                }
            }
        }

}

foobar_truncate_posts();
```

I use a plugin to handle my cronjobs. The Hock name is: `foobar_truncate_posts` and Arguments is `[]`

The cronjob works but it does not delete those post with the date of the customfield older than todays date. The two variables are the same.

`$currenttime_string` 20130820 
`$customfield_string` 20130820

Answer (score 1):

there's a typo in your code, you're missing an 's' at the end of `$result`.

This:

```
  foreach($result as $post){
```

Should be this:

```
  foreach($results as $post){
```

I just tried it out. Once you make that fix the wp_delete_post() works great.

---

EDIT

---

I'm really unclear on what you're trying to do. You want to check if the custom field is set to some time in the past? What purpose does the `continue` serve? Also, I'm guessing you're using Advanced Custom Fields (ACF). Using the jquery Date Picker, you can format your date to `Ymd` by default so you don't have to convert it to a DateTime object.

At any rate, this function should explain how to properly set and compare time values, you should be able to take it from there:

```
function foobar_truncate_posts(){
    global $wpdb;

    $currenttime = new DateTime();
    $currenttime_string = $currenttime->format('Ymd');

    # Set your threshold of max posts and post_type name
    $post_type = 'post_type_job';

    # Query post type
    $query = "
        SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts
        WHERE post_type = '$post_type'
        AND post_status = 'publish'
        ORDER BY post_modified DESC
    ";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($query);

    # Check if there are any results
     if(count($results)){
            foreach($results as $post){

                $customfield = get_field('bewerbungs_frist', $post->ID);
                $customfield_object = new DateTime($customfield);
                $customfield_string = $customfield_object->format('Ymd');

                if ( $customfield_string < $currenttime_string ) {

                    echo "The value of the custom date field is in the past";

                    $purge = wp_delete_post($post->ID);
                }
            }
        }

}

foobar_truncate_posts();
```

Comment: it is not working for me. Did you try it with a custom post-type and a custom-field for a date?

Comment: Another problem is that your "less than" comparison is trying to compare an object with a string, so it will crash your function. $currenttime has to be converted like this: `$currenttime_string = $currenttime->format('Ymd');`

Comment: `$currenttime_string` and `$customfield_string` have the same value. Today is the 20.08.2013 and if I post something with the customfield (ACF-Plugin) set to 19.08.2013 the cronjob does not delete this post.

Comment: what happens when you go: `echo $customfield`? Your customfield is probably set wrong.